# Is there a way to flatten a DF/CSV if the time for rows is the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I would like to flatten the DF so that what is currently ~8+ (depending) rows, into 1 row as the time associated is the same. I only want to overwrite `NaN` cells.

I'm reading the data in from a premade CSV.

```
    try:  
        csv = pd.read_csv(csv_path,usecols=lambda c: c in {"Time","Num","MyCols..."})
    except ValueError:  
        print("No Tracking Data")  
        return  
    csv = csv.dropna(thresh=2)
```

This returns a csv of ~20K rows at least.

Current format

| index | Time | Num | sts | fatal | proc | NG | Freq | Ax | Ay | .. | .. | .. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06:50 | 0 | 0x0000 | 0x0000 | 59 | 0 | 6000 | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- |
| 2 | 06:50 | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | 1201 | 1957 | 1283 | 1315 | 979 |
| 3 | 06:50 | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- |
| 4 | 06:50 | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- |

Desired format

| index | Time | Num | sts | fatal | proc | NG | Freq | Ax | Ay | .. | .. | .. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06:50 | 0 | 0x0000 | 0x0000 | 59 | 0 | 6000 | 1201 | 1957 | 1283 | 1315 | 979 |
| 8 | 06:51 | 0 | 0x0000 | 0x0000 | 59 | 0 | 6000 | 1400 | 1483 | 1260 | 1304 | 965 |
| 16 | 06:52 | 0 | 0x0000 | 0x0000 | 59 | 0 | 6000 | 1501 | 1827 | 1345 | 1340 | 982 |
| 24 | 06:53 | 0 | 0x0000 | 0x0000 | 59 | 0 | 6000 | 1401 | 1462 | 1239 | 1535 | 990 |

v:

[image: CSV Example]

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [mcve] and post at least your data in a format that is copy pastable. In general never post screenshot of data it is a very poor way to communicate textual data. Then the community will be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: can you add more clarification please, if you want to overwrite NaN cells only with the same value you can use `fillna` `pandas` function

Comment: Apologies about the lack of info, I've provided everything I can, I hope this alleviates some of the ambiguity.  I will go mess around with the fillna function and see if this solves it, thank you :)

Comment: To be sure, you aim to create complete lines from two split lines and meanwhile you want to keep an empty line for the same index? Or is the empty line not necessary and can it be discarded?

Comment: That is correct, however there are hundreds of columns, this is 10s of split lines sometimes. I wish to merge these splits into 1. The empty line can be discarded, I made a mistake there is no extra data associated with this num = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's fake some data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"time": "06:50", "A": 1}, {"time": "06:50", "B": 2}, {"time": "06:50", "C": 3},
    {"time": "06:51", "A": 4}, {"time": "06:51", "B": 5}, {"time": "06:51", "C": 6},
    {"time": "06:52", "A": 7}, {"time": "06:52", "B": 8}, {"time": "06:52", "C": 9},
]
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It looks like your sample:

```
    time    A    B    C
0  06:50  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  06:50  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  06:50  NaN  NaN  3.0
3  06:51  4.0  NaN  NaN
4  06:51  NaN  5.0  NaN
5  06:51  NaN  NaN  6.0
6  06:52  7.0  NaN  NaN
7  06:52  NaN  8.0  NaN
8  06:52  NaN  NaN  9.0
```

Then it should be as simple as:

```
frame = frame.melt(id_vars=["time"]).dropna()
frame = frame.pivot_table(index="time", columns="variable", values="value", aggfunc="first")
```

Which returns:

```
variable    A    B    C
time                   
06:50     1.0  2.0  3.0
06:51     4.0  5.0  6.0
06:52     7.0  8.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of the built in Python CSV library to parse the data. This would work on the fly and so would also not require much memory.

It works by reading groups of rows with the same `Time` value and then flattening them into a single output row.

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv

with open('input.csv') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output.writerow(header)
    
    for entry_time, input_rows in groupby(csv_input, lambda x: x[1]):
        output_row = []
        
        for input_row in input_rows:
            if output_row:
                for col, value in enumerate(input_row[2:], start=2):
                    if value not in ['', '--']:
                        output_row[col] = value
            else:
                output_row = input_row
        
        csv_output.writerow(output_row)
```